# In the revision view the code snippet runs old code

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, revision-history

In case someone posts a bad snippet and he or someone else fixes the code, the snippet runner in the revision view will play the old code.

Basically it will run the red and stroked code anyway. This really looks bizarre and doesn't look like it has any benefits to it. It actually makes it look like the edit was generally faulty.

The post where I've noticed is the second revision on [CSS style not looking far off from what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42379067/revisions)

However it's everywhere, in a post of mine it's clearly visible with the removed CSS still visible in the runner [Copy selected text to the clipboard WITHOUT using flash](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31192920/revisions)

You can verify this yourself, though for convenience:

[image: showing the bug]